# How get currentIndex() property from combobox inside table in Python

Tags: python, combobox, qtablewidgetitem

I am no so strong in object programing in Python, so I have to ask for a help.

I create a combobox inside table this way (it works):

```
self.comboBoxEng = QtGui.QComboBox()
self.tableWidget_1.setCellWidget(row,column,self.comboBoxEng)
```

The question is:
How to get `currentIndex()` property (for example...) from combobox which is used as `tableWidgetItem`?

Answer (score 2):

In one line

```
index = *self.tableWidget_1.cellWidget(row, column).currentIndex()
```

or any other info like `currenText()`.

Answer (score 0):

With this line you get cell widget out of table (in your case combo box)

```
comboBox = self.tableWidget_1.cellWidget(row, column)
```

and then simply take current index of that combo box:

```
index = comboBox.currentIndex()
```

Comment: Tell why you think this is the answer. Code only answers are low quality.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer I'm sorry, I was in hurry, I've edited my answer